# Tomcat Manager with mod_proxy and ROOT web application

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat6, mod-proxy

Our application runs in Tomcat6 and we're proxying all requests from Apache to Tomcat via mod_proxy.  that proxy config looks like:

```
ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
<Location />
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Location>
```

Our application is also deployed as ROOT.  I *think* that this is causing issues when attempting to get to the /manager URL but I'm not 100% sure and unclear on how I can verify this.  Can anyone give me some pointers on how to resolve this?  I'd like to use the manager app for remote deployments from jenkins.

Comment: if you're proxying all traffic "/" why go through the trouble of using a proxy at all? Could you use mod_jk instead?

Comment: I was actually against using Apache all together.  We're not serving any static content.  My suggestion was overruled, however.  Regarding mod_jk, all the recent reading I've done recommends mod_proxy over mod_jk.

Answer (score 0):

That configuration will route all traffic to Tomcat, including requests to /manager. The way to confirm this is to look at Tomcat's access log that should show the same requests as httpd's access log.

Answer (score 0):

Try http:// localhost/manager/html

It should work on both ports.